# PyQt5: subclassing QSlider (for promote in QtDesigner) with added lineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Basically, I want to add some QSliders to a window in QtDesigner, then "replace" them with a class that contains both a slider, and below it, a text box (a line edit).

---

EDIT: Why I want to do this: when I use QtDesigner, I can place sliders, and have an approximate visualization of the layout, as it is going to be in the final application:

[image: qt-designer-qsliders]

That is why I want to use QtDesigner to begin with - to get an approximate visualization of the final layout, as it is going to be in the application. And since I want to replace these sliders with some sort of a widget that is based on a slider, it is much more helpful for me to have the sliders, first and foremost, in the view.

However, if I have to place QWidget as a starting point for replacement where the sliders are, then the QtDesigner view looks like this:

[image: qt-designer-qwidgets]

In other words, that space which previously showed a slider, is now empty - and so now I do not have a preview of the final GUI layout anymore, which sort of defeats the purpose of using QtDesigner for me (I might as well go the hard way, and try to draw the GUI entirely in code, without any visual feedback, with all the time consumption that might entail).

---

So far, I managed to get to this - I implemented a subclass of QSlider called "VertSlider" in `test2.py`, then promoted the QSliders in QtDesigner to this class in `test2.ui`:

[image: test2.py]

Interestingly enough, it works somewhat - if you try looking hard at the center of the two sliders to the right, you can see the outline of the line edit in the center of the sliders.

But I don't want that, obviously - I'd want to have the line edit on bottom, it should take up as much vertical space from the original slider look (as specified in QtDesigner) as needed, and then the actual slider should fill up the rest of the vertical space (as indicated on the left of the screenshot).

I guess, part of the problem is, that QSlider does not seem to have a `.layout()` - that one by default returns "None"; I tried to force one, but that clearly does not work.

Via [Qt widget stacking child layouts on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672649/qt-widget-stacking-child-layouts-on-top-of-each-other) found this quote from [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout):

> If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget won't let you install another. You must first delete the existing layout manager (returned by layout()) before you can call setLayout() with the new layout.

So apparently, QSlider does not have a default layout manager .... And judging by [Is it possible to add text on top of a scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694821/is-it-possible-to-add-text-on-top-of-a-scrollbar) and [Qt add a widget inside another widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863891/qt-add-a-widget-inside-another-widget) - it seems in that case, I'd have to either "Subclass ... and override paintEvent()" or "Use a proxy style/`drawComplexControl()`"; by the terminology in https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/custom-widgets/creating-your-own-custom-widgets/ that would be a "custom-drawn widget", but I was really hoping that I could "just" do a "compound" widget: just somehow go from a QSlider-based specification in QtDesigner -> to a QSLider+QLineEdit widget, without having to deal with custom painting.

Of course, I can in principle subclass QWidget, and then the approach with `layout.addWidget` would work - but I cannot use that subclass to "promote" what is placed as a QSlider in QtDesigner.

So, what would be the easiest way to create a QSlider subclass, which would just add a line edit textbox on the bottom of the slider, which can be used as a class to promote QSlider to in QtDesigner?

`test2.ui`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>436</width>
    <height>354</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Want this:</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
               <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider">
                <property name="orientation">
                 <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
               <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
                <property name="maximumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>50</width>
                  <height>16777215</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
            <property name="text">
             <string>... by promoting these QSliders in QtDesigner:</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
            <item>
             <widget class="VertSlider" name="verticalSlider_2">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="VertSlider" name="verticalSlider_3">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>436</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>VertSlider</class>
   <extends>QSlider</extends>
   <header>test2</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

`test2.py`

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class VertSlider(QtWidgets.QSlider):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    QtWidgets.QSlider.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    print(self.layout()) # None
    # so, trying to force a layout here, so I could add a line edit - but it doesn't quite work:
    self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    self.label.setText("aa")
    self.label.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
    print(self.layout, self.layout.count(), self.label.width(), self.label.height(), self.label.x(), self.label.y()) # <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout object at 0x0000000006681790> 1 100 30 0 0


class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('test2.ui', self)
    self.show()

def main():
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MyMainWindow()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc answer is correct. The key is to use a QWidget as a container for QSlider and QLineEdit subwidgets. You can draw the QWidget in Qt Designer with it's subwidgets and then Promote it to your custom widget.

Comment: Thanks @bfris - I did finally manage to use the "*draw the QWidget in Qt Designer with it's subwidgets*" approach in QtDesigner, which allowed for both a decent preview in QtDesigner, and use of @ eyllanesc answer - posted a separate answer about that below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to promote a QSlider but a class that contains a QSlider, so the solution is to create that widget:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic


class CustomWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(orientation=QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(text="aa")
        # self.lineedit.setMaximumWidth(50)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.slider, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vlay.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        hlay.addLayout(vlay)
        spacer_item = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum
        )
        hlay.addItem(spacer_item)


class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test2.ui", self)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>436</width>
    <height>354</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Want this:</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
               <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider">
                <property name="orientation">
                 <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
               <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
                <property name="maximumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>50</width>
                  <height>16777215</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
            <property name="text">
             <string>... by promoting these QSliders in QtDesigner:</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
            <item>
             <widget class="CustomWidget" name="widget_2" native="true"/>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="CustomWidget" name="widget" native="true"/>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>436</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>CustomWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>test2</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ eyllanesc, +1 - that does indeed work in Python, however, it results with empty widgets in QtDesigner, which makes it more difficult for me to visually design a GUI (see my OP edit). However, I tried to also make use of the comment by @bfris - and came up with a way to both use your solution, and have visible sliders in QtDesigner; posted that as a separate answer.

Comment: @sdbbs I recommend you re-read your question since you nowhere indicate that you want to display the widget in Qt Designer, you clearly indicate that the problem is that your promoted widget does not work, so from my point of view my answer is correct, obviously other things can be built on an answer but I only focus on what the OP literally asks, and nothing else. If I focused on things not explicit then I could never finish writing an answer

Comment: Thanks, @eyllanesc - you are absolutely right, and I apologize for forgetting to mention that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have stated earlier, that it is important for me to start with an image of a slider in QtDesigner, because it helps me visually to design the GUI interface.

The solution from @eyllanesc works technically - however, then I have empty widgets in QtDesigner, which does not help me with visual design.

However, I tried this suggestion from the comment of @bfris:

> You can draw the QWidget in Qt Designer with it's subwidgets and then Promote it to your custom widget

... and I think I got to a solution that mixes the answer by @eyllanesc, and this approach, so I can both see sliders in QtDesigner, and subclass a QWidget.

First, after having added a widget (I just used the .ui from @eyllanesc answer as a starting point), just drag a vertical slider as its child in QtDesigner:

[image: qt-designer-add-qslider-to-qwidget]

At this point, however, the newly added slider will not be "aligned", because the widget that hosts it (the parent widget) does not have a layout (as indicated by the red circular cross-out icon at the bottom right of the widget icon in the Object Inspector tree view in QtDesigner). Here, just right-click the parent widget in the Object Inspector, and choose a layout (here I chose a horizontal layout):

[image: qt-designer-add-layout-to-qwidget-parent-of-qslider]

After this is done, the red circular cross-out icon at the bottom right of the widget icon disappears, and the sliders look reasonable in Qt Designer:

[image: qt-designer-qsliders-in-qwidgets-ok]

Now we can try the code. Basically, it is the same solution as in @eyllanesc's answer, except:

- The layout and the slider added to the QWidget in QtDesigner have to be deleted, before we do the new "subclass" layout
- However, when `__init__` of the widget subclass runs, it *does **not** yet* know that it has children from QtDesigner (the layout and the slider)
- Thus, the init has to run delayed, so we can first delete the children from QtDesigner (the layout and the slider) - and then we can populate with the "subclass" children (a new layout, and slider and line edit)
- However, in PyQt5 typically we have only deleteLater - but if we deleteLater the layout from QtDesigner, then we'll get *"QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to CustomWidget "widget_2", which already has a layout*" when we try to add the new subclass layout; so, we have to use `sip` module to delete the layout "now"

All this taken into account, the .py and .ui code is below, and it results with a GUI like this:

[image: pyqt5-subclassed-qtdesigner-gui]

... and this is basically good enough for me, as there is OK resemblance between the final GUI, and the one I can see in QtDesigner.

`test2.py`

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic
import sip

class CustomWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.printInfo("__init__:")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.delayedInit) # 10 ms later

    def printInfo(self, label=None):
        if label is None:
          label = "No-label"
        print(label, self.layout(), self.children())
        # above may print:
        # __init__: None []
        # delayedInit: <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000667eb80> [<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000667eb80>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSlider object at 0x000000000667ec10>]

        self.dumpObjectTree() # auto-prints to stdout
        self.dumpObjectInfo() # auto-prints to stdout

    def delayedInit(self):
        self.printInfo("delayedInit:")

        # delete contents of the pre-existing mock-up widget from QtDesigner
        for tchild in reversed(self.children()):
          #~ #tchild.setParent(None) # segfault
          #if type(tchild) is not QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout: # works, but better compare with self.layout():
          if tchild is not self.layout():
              tchild.deleteLater()
          else:
              print("Not deletingLater", tchild)
        # delete the layout of the pre-existing mock-up widget from QtDesigner;
        # must be "now" (via sip), not "later", else: "QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to CustomWidget "widget_2", which already has a layout"
        if self.layout() is not None:
            sip.delete(self.layout())

        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(orientation=QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(text="aa")
        # self.lineedit.setMaximumWidth(50)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.slider, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vlay.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        hlay.addLayout(vlay)
        spacer_item = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum
        )
        hlay.addItem(spacer_item)


class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test2.ui", self)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`test2.ui`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>436</width>
    <height>354</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Want this:</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
               <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider">
                <property name="orientation">
                 <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
               <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
                <property name="maximumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>50</width>
                  <height>16777215</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
            <property name="text">
             <string>... by promoting these QSliders in QtDesigner:</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
            <item>
             <widget class="CustomWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
               <item>
                <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_2">
                 <property name="orientation">
                  <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="CustomWidget" name="widget" native="true">
              <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
               <item>
                <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_3">
                 <property name="orientation">
                  <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                 </property>
                </widget>
               </item>
              </layout>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>436</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>CustomWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>test2</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Terminal printout when you run `test2.py`:

```
$ python3 test2.py
__init__: None []
CustomWidget::
OBJECT CustomWidget::unnamed
  SIGNALS OUT
        <None>
  SIGNALS IN
        <None>
__init__: None []
CustomWidget::
OBJECT CustomWidget::unnamed
  SIGNALS OUT
        <None>
  SIGNALS IN
        <None>
delayedInit: <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000668cdc0> [<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000668cdc0>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSlider object at 0x000000000668ce50>]
CustomWidget::widget
    QHBoxLayout::horizontalLayout_4
    QSlider::verticalSlider_3
OBJECT CustomWidget::widget
  SIGNALS OUT
        signal: destroyed(QObject*)
          <functor or function pointer>
  SIGNALS IN
        <None>
Not deletingLater <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000668cdc0>
delayedInit: <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000668c940> [<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000668c940>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSlider object at 0x000000000668cca0>]
CustomWidget::widget_2
    QHBoxLayout::horizontalLayout_3
    QSlider::verticalSlider_2
OBJECT CustomWidget::widget_2
  SIGNALS OUT
        signal: destroyed(QObject*)
          <functor or function pointer>
  SIGNALS IN
        <None>
Not deletingLater <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x000000000668c940>
```